# iOS library to embed PKCS#7 digital signature on PDF

Tags: gratis, library, pdf, ios

### Goal

I'm developing an iOS app (Swift) that will digitally sign PDF files. The following steps explain what it needs to do and how it will be used:

1. The user will open a PDF with my app.
2. My app will send a digest (SHA-256) of that PDF to a signature server.
3. The signature server will sign the digest and return a PKCS#7 signature.
4. My app has to embed the returned signature into the PDF.

In short, I need an iOS library that can embed a PKCS#7 digital signature into a PDF file. Please see detailed requirements below.

### Requirements

1. It needs to be a free library with license that enables usage on commercial products (my client doesn't want to buy a commercial solution).
2. It needs to work on iOS platform.
3. To be able to successfully sign a PDF, it has to:
4. Generate the signature field on PDF.
5. Generate the signature dictionary (generate PDF object and define byte range).
6. Embed the PKCS#7 signature into the signature dictionary.

### What I have tried

I found some commercial libraries that do what I need, like:

- [PSPDFKit](https://pspdfkit.com/guides/ios/features/digital-signatures/?search=signature)
- [PDFTron SDK](https://web.archive.org/web/20221130205508/https://www.pdftron.com/pdf-sdk/ios/)
- [Quick PDF Library 15](https://www.debenu.com/blog/debenu-quick-pdf-library-11-15-released.html)

And other commercial libraries that aren't native to iOS, but I can bridge with:

- [PDFBlackbox](https://www.nsoftware.com/sbb/)

And also libraries that doesn't work on iOS environment:

- [PDFBox](https://pdfbox.apache.org)

Besides that, I came across many documentations explaining the theoretical part of PDF signing and PDF in general:

- [Digital Signatures in a PDF](https://www.adobe.com/devnet-docs/acrobatetk/tools/DigSig/Acrobat_DigitalSignatures_in_PDF.pdf)
- [PDF Digital Signature Module V1.3 Specification for Client PDF signature](https://web.archive.org/web/20190809050155/https://rainbowpdf.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/DigSigv13_Client_Sig_manual.pdf)
- [PDF Reference](https://web.archive.org/web/20210925003249/https://wwwimages2.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/pdf_reference_archive/pdf_reference_1-7.pdf)

Comment: If you are already involving the server, why not have the server do everything related to the signing?

Comment: @Ryan For performance reasons. My client doesn't want to upload the PDF to the server and, after the signing, to download the signed PDF back to the device.